# linux: ranlib doesn't seem to add any new information into an archive file?

Tags: linux, gcc, indexing, archive

The man page of ranlib says:

DESCRIPTION
       ranlib generates an index to the contents of an archive and stores it in the archive.  The index lists each symbol defined by a member of an archive that is a relocatable object file.

Well, I tried to compile an archive file like below:

```
$ cat o.c
#include<stdio.h>
int f(){
  printf("hello\n");
  return 2;
}

gcc -o o.o -c o.c
ar rc libmyobject.a o.o
cp libmyobject.a libmyobject.a.keep
ranlib libmyobject.a
```

I tried to compare the size of library file beforand after ranlib, I got:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a   1626 Oct  3 12:03 libmyobject.a.keep
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a   1626 Oct  3 12:06 libmyobject.a
```

They're the same size. This is out of my expectation. I expect that runlib will store some extra information into .a file. But actually, the file size is still the same.

So what job does ranlib actually do, how can I check what job has ranlib done?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect a change in this case? The index will be the same in both cases - deterministic output of the command is desirable (I believe you're encountering the `--enable-deterministic-archives` configuration option of binutils)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If binutils is compiled with `--enable-deterministic-archives`, then by default, multiple runs of ranlib on the same input sources will produce the same output file because it nulls out the timestamp, uid and gid values.

You can force it to be non-deterministic by passing the `-U` flag, which will cause the storing of the timestamp, uid and gid values, and because the timestamp will have changed the files will be different:

```
$ ranlib -U libmyobject.a
$ diff libm*
Binary files libmyobject.a and libmyobject.a.keep differ
```

however the file **size** will remain the same, though.

```
$ ls -l libm*
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx xx 1618 Oct  3 13:58 libmyobject.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx xx 1618 Oct  3 13:58 libmyobject.a.keep
```

Bear in mind that determinism in tools like this is actually quite desirable, as it allows for features like [Reproducible Builds](https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds) to work without having to add convolutions to the build process.

Answer (score 0):

With modern GNU tools I don't know if it's actually possible to create an archive that doesn't have an index. `ar` creates the index by default, I don't see an option to not create one, and I don't see any command to remove it.

Running `ranlib` on an archive after you create it is something you do to make your build process work on older, crankier UNIX systems.